# Dataframe transformation based on repeating cell values based on column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe like this:

[image]

I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to transform it into this othe one:

[image]

I tried to generate all the combinations between **Time** column and **days** and then manually create the **Value** column by checking the given **Day-Time** cell, but Im sure it must be a more efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF the original index is not important for you**,
You could also use the `.melt()` method which has the advantage of grouping the days so you have the values for 1 day after another:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars='Time', var_name='Day', value_name='Value')
```

Result:

| index | Time | Day | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6am-2pm | Day1 | 15.4 |
| 1 | 2pm-10pm | Day1 | 15.0 |
| 2 | 10pm-6am | Day1 | 14.0 |
| 3 | 6am-2pm | Day2 | 13.4 |
| 4 | 2pm-10pm | Day2 | 2.1 |
| 5 | 10pm-6am | Day2 | 22.0 |
| 6 | 6am-2pm | Day3 | 45.0 |
| 7 | 2pm-10pm | Day3 | 3.4 |
| 8 | 10pm-6am | Day3 | 35.0 |

You could even rearrange the columns index like this to make it more readable in my own opinion:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=['Day','Time','Value'])
```

Result:

| index | Day | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Day1 | 6am-2pm | 15.4 |
| 1 | Day1 | 2pm-10pm | 15.0 |
| 2 | Day1 | 10pm-6am | 14.0 |
| 3 | Day2 | 6am-2pm | 13.4 |
| 4 | Day2 | 2pm-10pm | 2.1 |
| 5 | Day2 | 10pm-6am | 22.0 |
| 6 | Day3 | 6am-2pm | 45.0 |
| 7 | Day3 | 2pm-10pm | 3.4 |
| 8 | Day3 | 10pm-6am | 35.0 |

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_index` and `stack`:

```
out = (df.set_index('Time').stack().rename_axis(index=['Time', 'Day'])
         .rename('Value').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
         Time   Day  Value
0   6am – 2pm  Day1   15.4
1   6am – 2pm  Day2   13.4
2   6am – 2pm  Day3   45.0
3  2pm – 10pm  Day1   15.0
4  2pm – 10pm  Day2    2.1
5  2pm – 10pm  Day3    3.4
6  10pm – 6am  Day1   14.0
7  10pm – 6am  Day2   22.0
8  10pm – 6am  Day3   35.0
```